# Example of receiving a google appl engine application's email with php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email

Good day. I am trying to understand how to receive emails sent to a google app engine application. I read their tutorial but I still don't get it. According to the tutorial here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/#PHP_Receiving_mail my application's email address should be string@appid.appspotmail.com. Now my test application's id is emforwarder so I assume it's email address is string@emforwarder.appspotmail.com so I sent an email with hotmail. I have limited experience with python, as a side note hence thats why I chose php. I am using the Google App Engine Launcher to test the application locally. When I check the text file it is still empty. My aim to get the email to the php script which then writes the contents to file.

Here is my yam file app.yaml:

```
application: emforwarder
 version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/string@emforwarder.appspotmail.com 
script: handle_incoming_email.php
- url: /
script: main.php
login: optional

inbound_services:
- mail
```

Here is my handle_incoming_email.php file:

```
<?php
$astr = file_get_contents('php://input')
echo file_put_contents("bucket/mytest123.txt",$astr);
?>
```

Here is my main.php, which seems pointless but I included because the app engine launcher doesn't work without it:

```
<?php
 echo "hello world";
?>
```

My main.py is:

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.write('Hello world!')

 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
 ('/', MainHandler)
 ], debug=True)
```

I would appreciate a simple working example or tutorial very much.

Comment: For testing purposes can you change - url: /_ah/mail/string@emforwarder.appspotmail.com to - url: /_ah/mail/.+ 
Is your handle_incoming_email being called?

Comment: Are you running on the dev server? If so you need to send mail via the admin console.

Comment: I changed the main.php to call the handle_incoming_email.php directly to: <?php include("handle_incoming_email.php"); ?>. No I am on a vista. Also made the adjustment to ".+" but still nothing.

Comment: With your app running go back to the Google App Engine Launcher, make sure your app is selected, then click the SDK Console. Click 'Inbound Mail". The from is your hotmail account, to is string@emforwarder.appspotmail.com and what ever you want for the rest.

Comment: I checked there but I didn't find the hotmail email. That means that the app is not receiving the email,  i guess.

Comment: What you are trying to do is simulate an email being sent to your app. Simply fill in the information and send it. Because your on your home computer anything being sent from the internet won't be accessible. Either that or deploy your code. The second big issue is you can't write to files, you should look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/logs/ for your tests.